# Save data into table not working?

Tags: c#, sql

In my code below I call a method along with a reference to a list to save all data like name, age, gender and info from each object, but after I have tested my application, the table is empty! Have I missed something or done wrong? I get no error.

```
public void SaveDataToDB(List<Animal> animals)
    {
        connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        dataset = new DataSet();
        sql = "SELECT * From Guests";

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
            adapter.Fill(dataset, "Guests");

            foreach (Animal animal in animals)
            {
                DataRow row = dataset.Tables["Guests"].NewRow();
                row["Name"] = animal.Name;
                row["Age"] = animal.Age;
                row["Gender"] = animal.Gender;
                row["Info"] = animal.ImportantInfo;

                dataset.Tables["Guests"].Rows.Add(row);
            }
            new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
            adapter.Update(dataset.Tables["Guests"]);
            connection.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's possible you are getting no error because you're rethrowing the error in your catch clause. Remove the try..catch and see if it errors.

Comment: Please post the Guests table definition.

Comment: Sorry for stupid question, but how do I get that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your inserts to work correctly you need to define an `InsertCommand` for the adapter. Here is the sample:

```
public void SaveDataToDB(List<Animal> animals)
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
    string sql = "SELECT * From Guests";

    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
        adapter.Fill(dataset, "Guests");

        // Create the InsertCommand.
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
            "INSERT INTO Guests (Name, Age, Gender, ImportantInfo) " +
            "VALUES (@Name, @Age, @Gender, @ImportantInfo)", connection);

        // Add the parameters for the InsertCommand.
        command.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "Name");
        command.Parameters.Add("@Age", SqlDbType.Int, 4, "Age");
        command.Parameters.Add("@Gender", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 6, "Gender");
        command.Parameters.Add("@ImportantInfo", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100, "ImportantInfo");

        foreach (Animal animal in animals)
        {
            DataRow row = dataset.Tables["Guests"].NewRow();
            row["Name"] = animal.Name;
            row["Age"] = animal.Age;
            row["Gender"] = animal.Gender;
            row["Info"] = animal.ImportantInfo;

            dataset.Tables["Guests"].Rows.Add(row);
        }
        new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
        adapter.Update(dataset.Tables["Guests"]);
        connection.Close();
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Make sure to specify actual db types and sizes for db parameters.

Comment: Wouldn't this only update the in-memory DataSet? Not the actual Database Table?  I don't commonly use SqlDataAdapter for Inserts, only Selects, so I'm really unsure...

Comment: @Mark, neither do I, so I have just tested it locally, and this code updates the database as well.

Comment: Sweet! I'll have to consider for future development!  The only thing I don't like is hard coding the SQL into the application.  I tend to use stored procedures.

Comment: Opps! It seems like my code is working! Thanks Andrei for you code, but all that shouldn't be necessary. The point and the goal for tha applications that I'm working with is to work with the database in a disconnected mode as a comment to Mark. My problem now is why the list loss all it's data on the way to this method. No items in the list = nothing to save in database! :)